# Anyone care to explain the new "version" numbers?

Tags: support, revision-number

So I noticed the version numbers had changed from something like `build 5555` to this: `revision: 2010.5.14.1`. Now I understand the first part is today's date, but is the last part how many times they've changed something today? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), it's easy to [incorporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349782/creating-an-svn-repository-using-c) [build](http://florent.clairambault.fr/insert-svn-version-and-build-number-in-your-c-assemblyinfo-file) [numbers](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) into your source code.

In [April 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/), Jeff, etc. switched to [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). While it's not impossible to use build numbers, [it is more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386440/embedding-mercurial-revision-information-in-visual-studio-c-projects-automatical).

Looking at the number, it is likely they just used the date and number of releases per day (`Release 1, 14th of May, 2010`).

(For what it's worth, Jeff has posted a few thoughts [on](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html) [source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html) [control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a hash or version number related to their new source control system, Mercurial